# RGB to (L,a*,b*) conversion using an ICC profile

Tags: matlab, rgb, color-profile, color-management

I want to use MATLAB to convert rgb to Lab using AdobeRGB.icc. I know how to convert using srgb.icc.

```
         cform = makecform('srgb2lab');
         lab = applycform(rgb, cform);
```

However, I don't know how to use AdobeRGB.icc to convert. First, we can read icc profile by:

```
         p = iccread('AdobeRGB.icc');
```

But I don't know how to continue. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at `p` - does it contain a field "MatTRC"? (I hope so!)

This is most likely a `rgb2xyz` transform. (Check `p.Header.ConnectionSpace`)

Actually, if you look with `edit makecform` and dig into the code a little, you will see that if you call `makecform` with an input such as `'srgb2lab'` they just create two transforms, `'srgb2xyz'` and `'xyz2lab'`, and then apply them in sequence.  So we can do the same - using your icc profile for the `rgb2xyz` part, and the built-in for the `xyz2lab` part:

```
% 'forward' is rgb2xyz
cform1 = makecform('mattrc', p, 'Direction', 'forward');
cform2 = makecform('xyz2lab');
xyz = applycform(rgb, cform1);
lab = applycform(xyz, cform2);
```

Comment: Thank you! It has MatTRC, p.Header.ConnectionSpace='XYZ'

Comment: Then the above should work! Most of the *.icc files have an in internal (abc2xyz) transform (where abc = rgb, usually).  You can also use `makecform` with two sets of `icc` profiles to transform from one to another.